# What tools and libraries are available for implementing compilers targeting the CLR?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, clr

What compiler tools and supporting libraries are available that would help in implementing a compiler targeting .NET and the CLR? Preferably open source. I am especially interested in frameworks that implement a high-level IR and support for common high-level and middle-level optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

There's the Phoenix framework, which is now a bit dated (and not strictly open-source). A more modern but still very incomplete system is the [common compiler infrastructure](http://cciast.codeplex.com/). Sadly, no support for optimizations yet, but the "compiler as a service" system is expected in .NET 5.